# Is it possible to use an existing build for Karma testing in Angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I would like `ng test` to use the build that I have created with `ng build --prod`. What configuration has to be made to enable this behaviour? I want to be sure that I test exactly what goes to production rather than a separate build. (Let's assume I use default app created with `ng new App1` and no additional configuration was applied)

Comment: Tests are not made for a dedicated environment. You either allow the test to be run with the jasmine hooks or you don't...

Eventually, you could change the `test.js` file that is consumed by your `karma.conf.js`  to create a new type of extension to have custom sets of tests but I wouldn't recommend that since it's cumbersome for not much...